# Depois do SQLite meu aplicativo parou de funcionar

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo e precisei colocar o banco de dados `SQLite`, depois que coloquei quando vou abrir o aplicativo ele da um erro mostrando que o aplicativo parou de funcionar, perguntei para o meu professor de programação ele comentou que é um erro que acontece só na hora do `onCreate` da `activity` pois o restante da programação está certo, ele só não está criando o `onCreate`....

O código que acho que está dando erro seria essa parte:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_futebol_simples);
```

e o meu codigo completo e com o banco de dados é esse:

```
public class FutebolSimples extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageButton imgButton_play, imgButton_pause, imgButton_1, imgButton_2;
    private Button vermelho, amarelo;
    private TextView txt_valor1, txt_valor2;
    private EditText nomeTime1, nomeTime2;
    private int contador = 0;
    private int contador1 = 0;
    private Chronometer reloginho;
    long tempoPausado = 0;

    SQLiteDatabase db;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_futebol_simples);

        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        imgButton_1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_1);
        imgButton_2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_2);
        imgButton_play = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_play);
        imgButton_pause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgButton_pause);
        reloginho = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);
        txt_valor1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor1);
        txt_valor2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_valor2);
        nomeTime1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_time1);
        nomeTime2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lbl_time2);
        vermelho = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnvermelho);
        amarelo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAmarelo);




        imgButton_1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador++;
                txt_valor1.setText(" " + contador);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Goooool!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        imgButton_2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                contador1++;
                txt_valor2.setText(" " + contador1);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Goooool!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
        imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
        imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
        imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);


        imgButton_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_1.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_2.setEnabled(true);

                reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                reloginho.start();
                reloginho.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + tempoPausado);
            }
        });

        imgButton_pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imgButton_play.setEnabled(true);
                imgButton_pause.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_1.setEnabled(false);
                imgButton_2.setEnabled(false);

                tempoPausado = reloginho.getBase();
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                reloginho.stop();

            }
        });

        db = openOrCreateDatabase("Resultado", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS futebol (TimeOne VARCHAR, TimeTwo VARCHAR, FinalOne INT, FinalTwo INT);");

    }


    public void saveR (View view){

        if(txt_valor1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || txt_valor2.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || nomeTime1.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || nomeTime2.toString().trim().length()==0 || vermelho.getText().toString().trim().length()==0 || amarelo.getText().toString().trim().length()==0){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Por favor inicia uma partida!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return;
        }

        db.execSQL("INSERT INTO futebol VALUES('"+txt_valor1.getText()+"','"+txt_valor2.getText()+"','"+nomeTime1.getText()+"','"+nomeTime2.getText()+"','"+vermelho.getText()+"','"+amarelo.getText()+"');");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Partida Salva", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    public void listar (View view){
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM futebol", null);

        if (c.getCount() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Erro na pesquisa!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (c.moveToFirst()) {

            buffer.append("Nome: "+c.getString(0)+"\n");
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Resultado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
 }
```

A mensagem de erro que aparece quando clico no botão para chamar essa `Activity` é *"O aplicativo AllSports Beta parou."* clico em Ok e ele volta para a tela inicial do aplicativo.

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar vou ficar muito grato....

Comment: Posta o erro que você recebe!!

Answer (score 1):

Você não está inicializando o banco e já ta fazendo requisição.

Por exemplo:

```
db = new DBHelper(this);
```

---

Classe DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
   public DBHelper(){
      super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
   }
   public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
   public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

Ai você define nome do banco e versão que ele está atualmente.

Comment: Mas quando criei esse banco não cheguei a cria uma classe para o DBHelper, simplismente coloquei já dentro do onCreate eu precisaria criar uma classe?

Comment: Sim, você precisa dessa classe, eu editei minha resposta com um exemplo, da uma olhada.

Comment: ahh... tudo bem vou dar uma olhada, obrigado.

Comment: db = new DBHelper(this) fica no onCreate certo?

Comment: Amigo, fiz assim coloque o codigo DBHelper no mesmo codigo java e coloquei o db = new DBHelper(this); e está dando erro não sei porque... ele está dando erro no context, e o DBHelper diz que não esta sendo usado.

Comment: Cria uma classe separada pra ser o **DBHelpder**, e importa ela na sua classe, é melhor.

Comment: como que eu importaria a classe no projeto, tento import.android.java.DBHelper; e não está indo

Comment: Deixe o mouse em cima de onde vc quer importar, e aperta as teclas ALT + ENTER que ele busca exatamente onde a classe está e faz o import, isso se estiver usando o Windows, se for no Mac usa o atalho CMD + 1

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45385/discussion-between-nathan-and-leonardo-dias).